# using decimal the function returns wrong value

Tags: go, rounding

My function returns the wrong value for input value 2.3 - 229 is returned, but should be 230. This only happens with this value, otherwise everything works well. I already understood that the point is how float numbers are stored and how they are rounded. But I have not yet figured out how can I fix this function? shopspring/decimal, big.rat or big.int?

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "strconv"
)

func check_commission(number string) uint64 {
    tempValue, err := strconv.ParseFloat(number, 64)

    if err != nil || math.IsNaN(tempValue) || strconv.FormatFloat(tempValue, 'f', -1, 64) == "+Inf" {
        fmt.Println("Not a number:", number)
        return 0
    }

    if tempValue < 0 || tempValue > 99.99 {
        fmt.Println("Commission ", tempValue," out of range")
        return 0
    }

    var x = tempValue - math.Floor(tempValue)
    if x > 0 {
        tempValue *= 100
    }
    result := uint64(tempValue)

    return result
}

func main() {
    input := "1.5"
    fmt.Println("\nInput value:", input)
    fmt.Println("Output value:", check_commission(input))

    input = "15"
    fmt.Println("\nInput value:", input)
    fmt.Println("Output value:", check_commission(input))

    input = "2.3"
    fmt.Println("\nInput value:", input)
    fmt.Println("Output value:", check_commission(input))
}
```

The function checks the input value for correctness.
The point is that the size of the commission can be from 0 to 99.99. Maximum number of decimal places: 2.
Only integer values can return from a function, so the comma has to be shifted by 2 characters.
For example, for a commission of 1.5, the return value will be 150. And if 15, then 15 will return.

How to fix this function correctly? [Link to play go](https://play.golang.org/p/Expn7wuRK9J).

Comment: Do not use float for money. For this specific case multiply by 100 early, before Floor.

Comment: `uint64(tempValue)` will truncate decimal places.

Comment: What do you mean by "returns the wrong value on input value 2.3?" It returns exactly what you ask for: the truncated integer part of the floating point product of 2.3 * 100. Do you want to round the value instead?

Comment: @Zyl, only two decimal places are important

Comment: @BurakSerdar, then the integers will also be multiplied by 100, and I need only floats to be multiplied by 100. See the description of the function in the question

Comment: @Samuel By any chance you know your input type or better are you able to send int and float rather than string?

Comment: @Nick, this is according to the condition of the task

Answer (score 1):

Replace `uint64(tempValue)` with `uint64(math.Round(tempValue))`.

Running program at [play.golang.org](https://play.golang.org/p/2W_ITbpkBUw)

However I would be quite wary of using float for money, as mentioned in the comments.  I think you might want a "decimal" type (e.g., shopspring.decimal, as you asked above)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how to do it with shopspring/decimal?

Comment: shopspring/decimal has things to be wary of as well, e.g. https://github.com/shopspring/decimal/issues/211